# How to set end date not less than the start date in Twitter bootstrap's DateRangePicker?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker, daterangepicker

Im using twitter bootstrap's daterangepicker... I have a start date and an end date...
Problem here is...everytime i select a daterange...Start date can be greater than the end date(vice versa) when it comes to selection of dates... Is there a way to disable the dates during selection if this condition comes true? Thanks. BTW, datepicker validation onSelect doesn't work in here since i'm using DateRangePicker library :)

```
 $('#rangeFrom, #rangeTo').daterangepicker();
```

Comment: Are you using this daterangepicker? https://github.com/dangrossman/bootstrap-daterangepicker Looking at the basic example I can't get the start date to be greater than the end date.

Comment: thanks for this link... im trying now how i can make use out of this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [Dan Grossman's daterangepicker plugin](http://github.com/dangrossman/bootstrap-daterangepicker). It has this sort of date validation right out of the box.

He has also posted a [demo and several usage examples](http://www.dangrossman.info/2012/08/20/a-date-range-picker-for-twitter-bootstrap/).